# How to use traefik segments to route request to the right service on the right port of the same container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have a docker container that has 2 ports exposed, each for a different web service.
One is an API, the other is a simple web page with documentation.

I have tried to understand Traefik's doc. Looks like I need to use segments and I am failing miserably.

I want

- https://api.mydomain.net routed to port `my-container:4000`
- https://doc.mydomain.net routed to port `my-container:3000`

This is what I have now, which works but only serves port 4000

```yaml
  my-service:
    image: myregistry.com:5005/my-service:latest
    container_name: my-service
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.my-service-router.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.my-service-router.entrypoints=secure
      - traefik.http.routers.my-services-router.rule=Host(`www.mydomain.net`)
    networks:
      - internal
```

and I tried segments as follow

```yaml
  my-service:
    image: myregistry.com:5005/my-service:latest
    container_name: my-service
    expose:
      - 4000 # my API
      - 3000 # my doc
    labels:
      # segment myapi
      - traefik.myapi.port=4000
      - traefik.myapi.http.routers.my-service-router.tls=true
      - traefik.myapi.http.routers.my-service-router.entrypoints=secure
      - traefik.myapi.http.routers.my-services-router.rule=Host(`api.mydomain.net`)
      # segment mydoc
      - traefik.mydoc.port=3000
      - traefik.mydoc.http.routers.my-service-router.tls=true
      - traefik.mydoc.http.routers.my-service-router.entrypoints=secure
      - traefik.mydoc.http.routers.my-services-router.rule=Host(`doc.mydomain.net`)
    networks:
      - internal
```

but it's wrong isn't it?
so I tried different accordingly to the doc...

```yaml
  my-service:
    image: myregistry.com:5005/my-service:latest
    container_name: my-service
    expose:
      - 4000 # my service
      - 3000 # my other service
    labels:
      # segment myapi
      - traefik.myapi.port=4000
      - traefik.myapi.frontend.entrypoints=secure
      - traefik.myapi.frontend.rule=Host(`api.mydomain.net`)
      # segment mydoc
      - traefik.mydoc.port=3000
      - traefik.mydoc.frontend.entrypoints=secure
      - traefik.mydoc.frontend.rule=Host(`doc.mydomain.net`)
    networks:
      - internal
```

I am not understanding the doc, so any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Could you post your whole docker-compose file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that "mydoc" and "myapi" shouldn't be there:

```
my-service:
  image: myregistry.com:5005/my-service:latest
  container_name: my-service
  expose:
    - 4000 # my service
    - 3000 # my other service
  labels:
    # segment myapi
    - traefik.http.services.myapi.loadbalancer.server.port=4000
    - traefik.http.routers.myapi.entrypoints=secure
    - traefik.http.routers.myapi.rule=Host(`api.mydomain.net`)
    - traefik.http.routers.myapi.service=myapi
    # segment mydoc
    - traefik.http.services.mydoc.loadbalancer.server.port=3000
    - traefik.http.routers.mydoc.entrypoints=secure
    - traefik.http.routers.mydoc.rule=Host(`adoci.mydomain.net`)
    - traefik.http.routers.mydoc.service=mydoc
  networks:
    - internal
```

Also check that the traefik container is in the `internal` network too.

Comment: it worked. I need to wait 13 hours before I can award you with the bounty, will tomorrow. cheers